# Elastic-Search backup and restore

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, kibana

I am trying to take the snapshot of my indexes on my Amazon OpenSearch (the successor of Amazon ElasticSearch Service) domain using a lambda function.

My lambda function for the same is

```
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import requests
from datetime import datetime
#from datetime import time
import datetime
now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
print(now)
#now2 = time.now2()
def register_repo(host,region,service):
  credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
  awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
  # Register repository
  path = '_snapshot/backup_es' # the OpenSearch API endpoint
  url = host + path
  payload = {
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
      "bucket": "qa-domain-es-backup-s3-use1",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::133375953867:role/ArgusMemberPortal_LambdaRole"
    }
  }
  headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
  print(r.status_code)
  print(r.text)
  # Take snapshot
  path = f'_snapshot/backup_es/{now}'
  url = host + path
  r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth)
  print(r.text)

  #Restore snapshot
  # path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo-name/my-snapshot/_restore'
  # url = host + path
  # payload = {"indices": "my-index"}
  # headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  # r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
  # print(r.text)

  

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  host = 'https://vpc-qa-domain-ess2-use1-hyrawwu4edkpqqcusxvyywq7vi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/' # include https:// and trailing /
  region = 'us-east-1' # e.g. us-west-1
  service = 'es'
  register_repo(host,region,service)
```

on running the code above i get the following error

```
2023-02-20-14-58-29
START RequestId: f71ec64a-a60a-4119-ba94-15f0a542393e Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vpc-qa-domain-ess2-use1-hyrawwu4edkpqqcusxvyywq7vi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /_snapshot/backup_es (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f21b5747910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/es-backup-restore.py", line 48, in lambda_handler
    register_repo(host,region,service)
  File "/var/task/es-backup-restore.py", line 25, in register_repo
    r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/python/requests/api.py", line 132, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)END RequestId: f71ec64a-a60a-4119-ba94-15f0a542393e
REPORT RequestId: f71ec64a-a60a-4119-ba94-15f0a542393e  Duration: 130393.33 ms  Billed Duration: 130394 ms
```

I don't know why i am getting the error. Can someone please help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error it seems like the connectivity between Lambda and Elasticsearch on the HTTPS port is not correctly established. You need to check whether Lambda can connect to ES with HTTPS. You need to check the following

- Security groups: Check if ES and Lambda are in the same security groups
- Inbound rules: create a rule in the security group to allow access to Lambda to ES.
- Test the connectivity between Lambda and ES with some ES queries.